# How to put a background image on a div of a responsive login form?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have trouble putting a background image on a div of a login form done with bootstrap, but I have not managed to do it. The login page has the login form on the left and an image on the right.
Here I leave the code of what I have done:

File Login.php:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">

       <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>SOLVentas | Sales Systems</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/form-elements.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/style.css">


    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script 
        src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script 
         src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Favicon and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">

    <style type="text/css">

     div.container {
margin: 0 !important;
margin-right: 0 !important;
 padding-right: 0 !important;
padding-left: 0 !important;
  }

  #formulario, #imagen {
/*border: 2px solid red !important;*/
margin-right: 0 !important;
  }

   form input {
   padding: 10px !important;
   border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0,2) !important;
   height: 40px !important;

    }

    button {
    background-color: blue !important;
      }
    /*#imagen {

   background-image: url() !important;

          background-position: center center !important;

    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;

     background-attachment: fixed !important;

     background-size: cover !important;

    background-color: #66999 !important;

          } */
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>



           <!-- Top content -->

       <div class="container" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <div class="row" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="margin: 0; padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0; ">
            <div class="form-top">
                            <div class="form-top-left">
                                <h3>Get Access to your Account</h3>
                                <p>Insert your username and password to Log in:</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-top-right">
                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-bottom" style="background-color: #F3F3F3;">
                            <form role="form" id="frmIngresar" name="frmIngresar" method="post" class="login-form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">User</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="User..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="form-password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn">Log In</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8" style="background-image: url('img/backgrounds/1.jpg');  width: 66%; min-height: 100vh; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; margin: 0; padding: 0; "></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {   
            $("form#frmIngresar").submit(IngresarSistema);


        function IngresarSistema(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var user = $("#form-username").val();
            var pass = $("#form-password").val();

            $.getJSON("ajax/UsuarioAjax.php?op=IngresarSistema", {user: user, pass: pass}, function(r) {
                if (r) {
                    $(location).attr("href", "acceder.php");
                    //window.location.href = "acceder.php";
                } else {
                    bootbox.alert("Error! Username or password are not correct!");
                    $("#form-username").val("");
                    $("#form-password").val("");
                    $("#form-username").focus();
                }
            });  
        }

        });
    </script>

</body>
```

The result is something like that:

[image]

The image does not cover the entire right container. There is a kind of small margin to the right. If I put a width of 100% the image is lowered to the other row, being below the login form and that is not the idea.

The login page should look like this:

[image]

How could I get it? When the login is displayed on a mobile device with a resolution lower than 770px wide and 400px high I would like the image to no longer appear, only the form. But I do not know how to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `class="container"` to `class="container-fluid"`.